# Adding a regional language to Android speech

Tags: android-speech-api

I am new to android development in speech. I want to know whether it is possible to add a new regional language to android speech package (may be by creating new language model and dictionary and adding it to android). Plz help...

Comment: I think it's not in Android, rather the backend supporting speech engine which you use to recognize regional speech. If you use Google Speech API, then you are limited by what they provide, similarly Nuance

Comment: Is it possible to create backend supporting speech engine? May be in pocketsphinx or any other tool...?

Comment: PocketSphinx is configurable and flexible, you can model Language model and phonetic model so as it's supported by othe componenets in Sphinx, then you can flexibly use pocketsphinx